# Express route with multiple middlewares and separated layers

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'm reading the GitHub https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices and trying to apply the tips on my project. Currently i'm working on the "**1.2 Layer your components, keep Express within its boundaries**" tip, but I have a question.

I'm using routes/controllers, and using this tip (**1.2**), a route with multiple middlewares will look like this.

```
router.post("/do-multiple-stuff", 
       (req, res, next) => {
           stuffController.getStuffDone(req.body.stuff);
           next();
       },
       (req, res, next) => {
           stuffController.getOtherStuffDone(req.body.otherStuff);
           return res.send("stuff done");
        });
```

Is this correct? Or there's a better way to do this?

Thanks! <3

Answer (score 0):

The point of that 1.2 section is to create your business logic as a separate, testable component that is passed data only, not passed `req` and `res`.  This allows it to be independently and separately tested without the Express environment around it.

Your calls to:

```
stuffController.getStuffDone(req.body.stuff);
```

and

```
stuffController.getOtherStuffDone(req.body.otherStuff);
```

Are indeed making that proper separation between the web and the business logic because you aren't passing req or res to your controller.  That looks like it meets the point of the 1.2 training step.

The one thing I see missing here is that there isn't any output from either of these function calls.  They don't return anything and since you don't pass `req` or `res` to them, they can't be modifying the `req` object (like some middleware does) and can't be sending a response or error by themselves.  So, it appears that these need a mechanism for communicating some type of result back, either a direct return value (if the functions are synchronous) or returning a promise (if the functions are asynchronous).  Then, the calling code could get their result and do something with that result.